# Play!Framework & Akka tell

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, future

In integrating Akka with Play (have to use Java 7), what I want is for a controller action to fire-and-forget a message to an actor.  However, I want the actor to send the response of it's work to the client that sent the http request.

I've successfully tried this with use of ask() in my controller... and want to change it to use tell().  It was "easy" as ask returns a Future.

I know that I need to return a Promise.

I "understand" Future in Akka - just not able to stitch a story together on:

- I'm imagining that in the controller, I can compose a message and pass the `Http.Context` - `current()` ? - I actually want the `Http.Request`, `Http.Response` and maybe the `Http.Session`
- send this message to a router actor using `tell`
- what does the controller return ?? where is my `Promise< Result>` - am I to create a Future that wraps the tell() ?  If so, how?
- a worker actor does the work (which could mean serializing some JSON object over Http.Response) and sends a reply to the sender -- which who ?? Play Action?? Imagining that it's a Future in the controller, I would then map the Future< ?> to a `Promise< Result>` ??

(something about the above list isn't jiving...)

Why struggle with this? I want to follow the advise in using tell() - http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
s-

Answer (score 5):

You can implement it in the same way as the article suggests. Create a per-request actor which on success or failure would complete a promise for which the future is being returned in the play controller.

So your controller would look something like this (sorry, code is in Scala and not compiled):

```scala
def index = Action.async {
  val responsePromise = Promise[String]
  Akka.system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyPerRequestActor], responsePromise))
  responsePromise.future.map(Ok(_))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martynas.  Trying to understand the scala. So, Props seems to take Seq[Any] as arguments (after the actor class).  We are passing a promise which is to return a String.  And when the Promise is satisfied we take the Result (i.e., Future) and map it to the response. Is that correct? Wondering what the receive() in MyPerRequestActor has to do ... send a message to Sender ? Just realized that there's an activator for Per-Request-Actor & Spray... checking it out.

Comment: so... digesting PerRequest activator code.
I get there's a PerRequest actor, which when created (?) sets a 2 sec timeout, sends a tell to the target (would this be something that goes into java preStart?).

Comment: I like the complete() which ensures that the PerRequest actor is stopped. Looking at RestRouting, I don't understand how petsWithOwner gets a ctx (which becomes the request context for PerRequest). could you help me understand that line? I do see that GetPetsWithOwner is created by PerRequest therefore when DummyAppCore does a tell to context.parent it'll come back to PerRequest?? whats Validation?

Comment: @SheshadriMantha You can use `preStart` or the `Actor` constructor, there is not much difference. They do the same thing by default which is to run when the actor starts and again every time the actor is restarted. If you like, you can override `postRestart` to not call `preStart` after a restart, since we would not really need to send the timeout message a second time if the actor restarted. It's not a big deal either way.

Comment: @SheshadriMantha I've not used Play a great deal, but I believe in the above example, `MyPerRequestActor` would not not need to send a message to sender, it would just need to call `complete()` on the `Promise` and stop itself when the response is ready to go. `Promise.complete` is the Play equivalent of `context.complete` in spray - they both are called to send the response back to the client.